# Mysql eliminate user based on conditions

Tags: mysql

I asked this last week over the weekend and it got buried in the archives before anyone could answer. So forgive me if you've already seen this.

I teach classes and want to be able to select those students who have taken one class, but not another class. I have two tables: lessons_slots which is the table for every class such as:

> --------------------
> -ID   name     slots-
> -1    basics   10   -
> -2    advanced 10   -
> -3    basics   10   -
> ---------------------

The other table is class_roll, which holds enrollment info, such as:

> --------------------
> -sID   classid     firstname    lastname-
> -1     1           Jo           Schmo
> -2     1           Person       Two
> ...
> -13    2           Jo           Schmo
> ---------------------

What I want to do, I select everyone who has not had the advanced class (for example). I've tried doing

> SELECT * 
> FROM lessons_slots 
> LEFT JOIN class_roll
> ON lessons_slots.ID = class_roll.classid
> WHERE lessons_slots.name != 'advanced'

But that doesn't work...All it does is eliminate that row, without eliminating the user. I want Jo Schmo, for example, to not show up in the results. Any ideas?

Comment: Poor schema complex query difficult make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty, but works.

```
 SELECT c.*
FROM lessons_slots l
join class_roll c on l.id=c.classid
where concat(firstname,lastname) not in (select concat(firstname,lastname)
from  lessons_slots l
join class_roll c on l.id=c.classid where name='advanced')
```

Comment: I get an error that says, "subquery returns more than one row"

Comment: Got it! That did it beautifully! (I wish I had asked first before spending several hours swearing at my computer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM class_roll cl LEFT JOIN lessons_slots ls  
ON cl.classid = ls.id AND ls.name != 'advanced'
```

So you actually want to delete rows? Well then:

```
DELETE FROM class_roll cl LEFT JOIN lessons_slots ls  
ON cl.classid = ls.id AND ls.name != 'advanced'
```

Comment: That has the same problem as my original query...it eliminates the row without eliminating the user. So...it would get rid of sID 13, but wouldn't eliminate Jo Schmo entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something to the effect of

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM class_roll
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM class_roll, lesson_slots 
    WHERE class_roll.classid = lesson_slots.ID
    AND lesson_slots.name = 'advanced')
```

You can then use the result as the basis of a DELETE query.